# Conditional function plot in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, chemistry

I'm looking into the stability of solution of a set of chemical rate equations. There is a set of rate constants {$k_i$} I which to manipulate, and I want to find the stable solutions where

$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial k_i} = f \left(k_1, k_2, k_3, ...,x_1, x_2,x_3 \right) = 0$.

for all $x$ (The specific set of equations I'm working with, has no analytic solution). I have a set of liens which produce for a specific set of values of {$k_i$} a list of the norm of the solutions, and a corresponding list saying for these solutions if they are stable or not. I want to feed these lines of code in `Manipulate`, and plot the stable and unstable values as a function of one of the rate constants $k_i$. How can I do that? Note that in my case I cannot derive an analytical solution so I cannot derive a general formula first. Also, the number of solutions isn't necessarily fixed.

Edit (Removed misplaced line and add example.)

Take this simple example:

```
f1 = u*r - u^2; (*the function to look into*)
J = D[f1, u]; (*the Jacobi matrix*: {r-2u}*)
solutions = Solve[f1 == 0, u]; 
(*solve the function: {u->0,u->r}*)
J = Table[J /. solutions[[jj]], {jj, Length[solutions]}]; 
(*assign the solution to the Jacobi matrix*)
evals = Table[Eigenvalues[J[[jj]]], {jj, Length[J]}] 
(*find the eigenvalues of the matrix*) 
stability = Table[evals[[jj]] < 0, {jj, Length[evals]}] 
(*the stability critercia*)
```

Now if I plot the two solutions I got ($u=0,~u=r$) as a function of $r$ I get two lines:

[image]

one for the case when the appropriate eigenvalue is greater than 0 (unstable solution) and one when it is smaller (stable solution). How do I generate that plot in `mathematica` and how do I apply this to manipulate?

Edit 2: (Update on some progress, still there is a style problem)

This is my current code, I couldn't avoid the need of functional programming which I understand is bad `Mathematica` practice.

```
play[rr_] := Module[{rin = rr}, (*define  a function*)
  f1 = x*r - x^2; (*the function to check*)
  J = D[f1, x]; (*Jacobi matrix*)
  f1 = f1 /. {r -> rin}; (*assign values*)
  J = J /. {r -> rin};
  solutions = Solve[f1 == 0, x]; (*two solutions*)
  J = Table[J /. solutions[[jj]], {jj, Length[solutions]}]; (*assign the values to the Jacobi matrix*) 
  stability = Table[J[[jj]] < 0, {jj, Length[J]}]; (*single elemnt matrix, the eigenvalue is the single element in the matrix*)
  Values[solutions] (*return the solutions*)
  ]

Manipulate[Plot[play[r] /. x -> u, {r, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}], {u, -10, 10}]
```

This results with this plot:

[image]

Which looks similar, but I still have two problems:
1. How do I make sure that the first solution is the stable one and the second is the unstable one?
2. How do I make the two plot line to be different?

Edit 3: another (relatively small) issue:

I cannot assign the value of my "x axis" to the plot after the solution because finding the solution and the eigenvalues of my matrix becomes too complicated.

Comment: Its not very clear from your question. Can you give few of your equations or functional form in Mathematica?

Comment: @Sumit, I've added an example to my solution, hope it helps to clear my meaning.

Comment: `J = D[f1, u];` is just a function, not a matrix, so `EigenValues` does not make any sense. I think you need two functions and two variables to get a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: @Sumit, Right, but this is not my main issue. I've made some progress; I'll update my question in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

As much I understand you want to see if your solutions are stable or not from the eigenvalues of the Jacobian. Since you can not have the eigenvalues for your case, I put the condition on the solution itself.

```
Manipulate[
 f1 = u*r - u^2;(*the function to look into*)
 J = D[f1, u];(*the Jacobi matrix*:{r-2u}*)
 solutions = u /. Solve[f1 == 0, u]; (*solve the function:{u->0,u->r}*) 
 J = (J /. u -> #) & /@ solutions;
 (*evals = Eigenvalues[J];*)
 stability = If[# <= 0, "Unstable", "Stable"] & /@ solutions;
 Grid[{{"Sol1", "Sol2"}, solutions, stability}, Frame -> All]
 , {r, -1, 1}]
```